# angular post method dynamically payment gateway Error : TypeError: this.element.submit is not a function

Tags: angular, post, submit

I have created post method on html side in angular

```
<form  #bankUrlForm name="bankUrlForm"   action="{{bankTranactionModel.sendToBankUrl}}" method="post" target="_self"  >
  <input type="hidden" name="RefId" [ngModel]="bankTranactionModel.refId">
</form>
```

And get `bankTranactionModel` data from server
and correctly fill data, action url, refid, ...
and on code behind

```
 @ViewChild('bankUrlForm') bankPostMethod;
```

and call the submit

```
this.bankPostMethod.submit();
```

I get error

```
TypeError: this.bankPostMethod.submit is not a function
```

[image]
[image]

and I have also used `ngform` but I get error.

and when use this

```
@ViewChild('bankUrlForm') bankPostMethod: ElementRef<HTMLFormElement>;
```

redirect page and show error

```
masspurchase:1 POST http://localhost:4200/purchase/masspurchase 404 (Not Found)
```

[image]

Comment: your second error means that you don't have any endpoint with : `/purchase/masspurchase` address. what is the value of `bankTranactionModel.sendToBankUrl` ? it's probably because you're not sending enough post data (or auth params) to the bank url, so it will get redirected. (بووووووورررس چه خبر؟ (بوکمارک ات) :دی )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do it this way and it worked Maybe it's wrong use javascript on typescript

```
var form = document.createElement("form");
          form.setAttribute("method",sendMethod);
          form.setAttribute("action", bankUrl);
          form.setAttribute("target", "_self");
          var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
          hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "RefId");
          hiddenField.setAttribute("value", refIdValue);
          form.appendChild(hiddenField);
          document.body.appendChild(form);
          form.submit();
          document.body.removeChild(form);
```

Answer (score 2):

`@ViewChild('bankUrlForm')` returns `ElementRef` of `HTMLFormElement` in your case:

```
@ViewChild('bankUrlForm') bankPostMethod: ElementRef<HTMLFormElement>;
```

So in order to access native [HTMLFormElement.submit()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit) method you need to write:

```
this.bankPostMethod.nativeElement.submit();
```

Comment: thanks for reply , I tested but i get error, my current url is 'http://localhost:4200/purchase/masspurchase' and i get error  'POST http://localhost:4200/purchase/masspurchase 404 (Not Found)' page redirect to http://localhost:4200/purchase/masspurchase url and show blank page with text 'Cannot POST /purchase/masspurchase'

Comment: It should submit your form to url which is defined in `action` attribute of `<form/>`. So it works as expected. What do you want me to fix here?